# Select preceding sibling of a matched sibling using XPath?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have the following code:

```
<include>
  <fallback>
    <title>Content</title>
  </fallback>
</include>
<include>
  <fallback>
    <title>Content</title>
  </fallback>
</include>
<include> <-- I want this.
  <fallback>
    <title>Content</title>
  </fallback>
</include>
<adhoc>
  <title>Content</title>
</adhoc>
<include>
  <fallback>
    <title>Content</title>
  </fallback>
</include>
```

I need to find the third `<include>` because it has `<adhoc>` as its direct following-sibling. Is there away to find this with XPath?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *"I need to find the third `<include>` because it has `<adhoc>` as it's direct following-sibling."*

This requirement can be translated to XPath as follow :

```
//include[following-sibling::*[1][self::adhoc]]
```